# Greystripe sdk ( for ads ) crash issue 

Tags: iphone, crash, ads

Has anybody integrated Greystrip sdk in their application for showing ads. I am facing crash issues with sdk and don't know how to overcome with it.

Although I have send a mail with the attachment to the greystripe-sdk people, I am posting the crash logs here for the reason somebody else would have seen them before and overcome through them.

Or Do you people know any ad showing sdk which shows ads in full-screen from beginning.

Thanks,

Madhup

```
**This is the crash log when the ad is going to be displayed.**
```

-#0  0x30011940 in objc_msgSend ()

-#1  0x000306a8 in -[GSContentController viewDidAppear:] (self=, _cmd=, a_animated=) at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSContentController.m:1012

-#2  0x00033532 in -[GSController presentControllerAnimationDidStop:finished:context:] (self=, _cmd=, a_string=, a_finished=, a_context=0x5f1f710) at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSController.m:612

-#3  0x000346b6 in -[GSController presentController:animated:] (self=0x11e2d0, _cmd=, a_controller=0x1204f0, a_animated=0 '\000') at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSController.m:298

-#4  0x00045874 in -[GSStandardCommandHandler displayContent:] (self=0x13b0f0, _cmd=, a_display=) at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSStandardCommandHandler.m:671

-#5  0x3020ee44 in **invoking_** ()

-#6  0x30262ac6 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()

-#7  0x30262a48 in -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] ()

-#8  0x000366f8 in -[GSJavascriptBridge forwardInvocation:] (self=, _cmd=, a_invocation=) at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSJavascriptBridge.m:359

-#9  0x30218094 in ***forwarding*** ()

-#10 0x3020eda0 in **forwarding_prep_0_** ()

-#11 0x3020ee44 in **invoking_** ()

-#12 0x30262ac6 in -[NSInvocation invoke] ()

-#13 0x00036ea2 in -[GSJavascriptBridge executeCocoaCommand:] (self=0x13c810, _cmd=, a_commandString=0x5f1a9b0) at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSJavascriptBridge.m:419

-#14 0x00037000 in -[GSJavascriptBridge poll] (self=0x13c810, _cmd=) at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSJavascriptBridge.m:385

-#15 0x3050e47e in __NSFireTimer ()

-#16 0x30254a0e in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()

-#17 0x3025416a in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()

-#18 0x320452a4 in GSEventRunModal ()

-#19 0x308f037c in -[UIApplication _run] ()

-#20 0x308eea94 in UIApplicationMain ()

```
**This crash also occurs when ad is about to display.**
```

*** -[WAKScrollView makeKeyAndVisible]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1e7470

```
**This crash happens when the ad is closed by pressing the skip button on the screen.**
```

*** -[NSCFString setHidden:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1b6cf0

Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.
(gdb) where
-#0  0x30011940 in objc_msgSend ()

-#1  0x000348a2 in -[GSController dismissController:animated:] (self=0x11e6f0, _cmd=, a_controller=0x120840, a_animated=0 '\000') at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSController.m:307

-#2  0x000459a2 in -[GSStandardCommandHandler displayContent:] (self=0x114170, _cmd=, a_display=) at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSStandardCommandHandler.m:676

-#3  0x0004578e in -[GSStandardCommandHandler actionSheet:didDismissWithButtonIndex:] (self=0x114170, _cmd=, a_actionSheet=, a_buttonIndex=374296) at /greystripe/source/platforms/iPhone/SDK/Classes/GSStandardCommandHandler.m:767

-#4  0x30a72d44 in -[UIActionSheet(Private) _alertSheetAnimationDidStop:finished:] ()

-#5  0x3093b028 in -[UIViewAnimationState sendDelegateAnimationDidStop:finished:] ()

-#6  0x3093aec0 in -[UIViewAnimationState animationDidStop:finished:] ()

-#7  0x3293a43c in run_animation_callbacks ()

-#8  0x3293a244 in CA::timer_callback ()

-#9  0x30254a0e in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()

-#10 0x3025416a in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()

-#11 0x320452a4 in GSEventRunModal ()

-#12 0x308f037c in -[UIApplication _run] ()

-#13 0x308eea94 in UIApplicationMain ()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys I found out the solution. So I just want to share my thoughts.

The greystripe documentation clearly says, stop all Update and Rendering while an Ad is displayed.

What I was doing was a mistake that I called the ad display method before my alert was dismissed and recalled to show the alert from adWillClose. That caused issues for 2 days to sort out the problem.

Now I am calling the adDisplay and alert Methods with delay of 0.1 seconds and the problem is gone.

**EDIT:** You can also check this link... http://www.torquepowered.com/community/forums/viewthread/105119

Hope this will help to some body else too.

Thanks,

Madhup

Answer (score 1):

Greystripe support here. I sent you some follow-up questions via email.

I'll be sure to post the solution here, once we've got this figured out, for anyone playing along at home.

Comment: Thanks Josh I got your mail, unfortunately I was calling to show a UIAlertView from adWillClose, I fixed that last night, and its working perfectly. Thanks